# Add a binding conditionally To Octopus Deploy

Tags: deployment, octopus-deploy

I'm trying to add a binding conditionally.

I would like the binding to be added if the variable exists.

Eg say there exists `foo, "hello I'm foo", Production`, but no such `foo` vairable exists for `beta`, then the binding would get added to Production by not beta.

I think my expression should look something like this:

```
#{if foo } True #{if}
```

I got this idea from a question asked [here](http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/3089-different-number-of-iis-bindings-on-website-deployment-for-different-enviroments).

I'm having trouble with making the basic expressions work however:

```
#{if 1 == 1} True #{if}
```

[image: Add binding]

The binding above fails with error

> "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."

**How do fix this?**

Comment: This also matches what I'm trying to do, but the suggested solutions aren't working: http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/5779#comment_38717220

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha - looks like a small syntax error on your first attempt:

```
#{if foo}True#{/if}
```

You were missing the slash to close the expression!

You could extend this to put the value of `False` in too, if required by the step:

```
#{if foo}True#{/if}#{unless foo}False#{/unless}
```

Documentation: https://octopus.com/docs/reference/variable-substitution-syntax#VariableSubstitutionSyntax-Conditionalsconditionals

---

It is worth noting that this is exactly what variable scoping is for... so why not create a variable for `foo`, unscoped, with a value of `False`. Then you can have a second "copy" of `foo` with a value of `True` in the scope of Production only.

This would mean that your process step would simply have `#{foo}` as the value.

---

P.S. there was a bug in the expression syntax that was recently fixed (v 3.8.3) that you may have been feeling the pain of:

Release notes: https://octopus.com/downloads/compare?from=3.7.18&to=3.8.3

Specific Issue: https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/3089